# How to yield a list to stream values to flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list which is dynamically generated by querying the database, but for the purposes of this question, I use a static list for demonstration.

I want to stream values to a web page so I thought a generator is best to use. Below is my python code:

```
list111 = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in list111:
    def events():
        print(i)
        yield "data: %s\n\n" % (i)
    return Response(events(), content_type='text/event-stream')`
```

I am expecting this script to print 1 to 5 but instead it keeps on printing 1. Is it the wrong way to yield a list?

This is what I am using on the client side (for reference purposes):

```javascript
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('/upload');
  console.log(source)
  source.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    var byte = e.data;
    console.log(e.data)
  }
}
```

Comment: You return in the first iteration of the loop, so it only returns the `events` generator yielding a single "data: 1\n\n".

Comment: should I add return inside events

Comment: You want to return a generator yielding several strings? Put the loop inside `events`

Comment: @L3viathan thanks got it.

Answer (score 3):

I got it as @L3viathan pointed out I am returning after the first iteration only. What I need to return was the for loop inside my event function.

```
 list111 = [1,2,3,4,5]
 def events():
     for i in list111:
        print(i)
        yield "data: %s\n\n" % (i)
 return Response(events(), content_type='text/event-stream')`
```